# How to manually install arpjs module for node.js?

Tags: node.js, module

I am trying to install arpjs module... when I try to install it with

```
npm install arpjs
```

or

```
npm install  
sudo npm install https://github.com/skepticfx/arpjs.git
```

I always get this error:

> npm WARN lifecycle typechecker@2.0.8~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) typechecker@2.0.8 node ./cyclic.js /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/typechecker-8e5299d6dc600530516e3f6be254ad7d
>
> socketwatcher@0.2.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/arpjs/node_modules/socketwatcher
>   node-gyp rebuild
>
> make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/arpjs/node_modules/socketwatcher/build'
>
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/socketwatcher/socket_watcher.o
>
>   In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:190:0,
>
>                        from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:80,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.hpp:8,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.cpp:5:
>
>   ../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::Signature>::return_t
>
>   NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::New(NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH, int, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH*)’:
>
>   ../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:181:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH&, int&, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH*&)’
>          return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
>                                                                                   ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:181:76: note: candidate is:
>       In file included from /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node.h:42:0,
>                        from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:24,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.hpp:8,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.cpp:5:
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:4674:27: note: static v8::Local<v8::Signature> v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>)
>          static Local<Signature> New(
>                                  ^
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:4674:27: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 4 provided
>       In file included from ../socket_watcher.hpp:8:0,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.cpp:5:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: At global scope:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:171:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
>        NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
>                                ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:166:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
>        NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
>                                ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:564:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
>            , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
>                    ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:564:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
>            , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
>                                          ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:568:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
>                v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
>                                                         ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:568:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
>                v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
>                                                                   ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:575:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
>            return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
>                                                                          ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:575:67: note: candidates are:
>       In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:25:0,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.hpp:8,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.cpp:5:
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
>        NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
>                                               ^
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
>        NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
>                                               ^
>       /home/groshev/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
>       In file included from ../socket_watcher.hpp:8:0,
>                        from ../socket_watcher.cpp:5:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:579:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size)’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
>            return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
>                                                                    ^
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
>       ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:586:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
>            return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
>                   ^
>       make: *** [Release/obj.target/socketwatcher/socket_watcher.o] Error 1
>       make: Leaving directory`/usr/lib/node_modules/arpjs/node_modules/socketwatcher/build'
>       gyp ERR! build error 
>       gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>       gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-52-generic
>       gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/arpjs/node_modules/socketwatcher
>       gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
>       gyp ERR! not ok 
>       npm WARN install:socketwatcher@0.2.1 socketwatcher@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>       npm WARN install:socketwatcher@0.2.1 Exit status 1
>       /usr/lib
>       └── (empty)

```
npm ERR! code 1
```

so i was thinking to manually download the sorurce form github and install it . But this module is dependent of other modules (ip,mac and pcap).
So how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with the latest release of arpjs (1.1.0). Try installing arpjs again using `npm install arpjs`